# android chat ListView getView updating wierdly

Tags: android, listview

i've built a chat application.

inside my chat messages Activity, i have a ListView which shows all text message.

inside each text messages i have a TextView which will by default write `"Sending..."` and i want it to be updated after the message is sent.

inside each ChatMessage object i have a `sent` and `time` property. if sent is true i will show in the TextView the time, and if it's false i will write `"Sending"` as written above.

when i'm sending a new message, i'm adding a new view to the ListView adapter, and from some reason it shows that message was sent although it didn't... can't really understand why.

this is my ArrayAdapter's getView() and holder class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView; 
    ChatMessage chatMessage = chatMessagesArrayList.get(position);
    ChatMessageHolder chatMessageHolder = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        if (chatMessage.getSenderId() == app.getFacebookCurrentUser().getId())
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
        else
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.chat_green, null);

        chatMessageHolder = new ChatMessageHolder();
        chatMessageHolder.message = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.activity_chat.message);
        chatMessageHolder.sentTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.activity_chat.sent_time);
        chatMessageHolder.isSent = chatMessage.isSent();            
        row.setTag(chatMessageHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        chatMessageHolder = (ChatMessageHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    chatMessageHolder.message.setText(chatMessage.getMessage());
    if (chatMessageHolder.isSent)
        chatMessageHolder.sentTime.setText(app.getDateTime(chatMessage.getTime()));

    return row;
}


private static class ChatMessageHolder
{
    TextView message, sentTime;
    boolean isSent = false;
}
```

i can't really understand why doesn't it write the time or "Sending..." according to the isSent boolean flag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the ListView recycles previous views (that's what the `convertView` variable is). Likely it's recycling another view that was already set to "Sent", and you're never handling the alternate case where `chatMessagerHolder.isSent` is false. You should avoid setting `chatMessageHolder.isSent = chatMessage.isSent();` until after that first if-else block. That first if-else should just be to initialize the view or recycle the object. Also, when you check `if(chatMessageHolder.isSent)` you should also handle what the `TextView` should say if that is false (i.e. in a followup else statement) since the views are recycled.

Comment: starting at the end, i'm setting the last if statement to false because inside my XML file it is set to "Sending..." so there is no need to do so.
i didn't quite understand where should i put the isSent if statement? should i maybe not use the holder for this and just use the ChatMessage in that position to determine the state ?

Comment: ohhh i've now understand why you said i must have a false statement as well.. be cause maybe the view is recycled and using some other ChatMessage properties ?

Comment: Yup, exactly. The ViewHolder simply maintains references to the Views inside your inflated layout. If the view is recycled, you can get these references by getting the tag you set in the initialization (where you are setting the ViewHolder as a tag). It doesn't matter if you've set "sending..." in the XML, because when you recycle a view, it isn't re-inflating from the XML, it's reusing one you've used before, one which you may have already used to set to "Sent". You always have to handle all cases in a getView due to this recycling.

Comment: got it.. it actually make sense when you understand it... thanks! :)

Comment: i have the same problem with my bubbles of the chat message... it is determine inside the first if condition in the LayoutInflater. how can i change the view after this if condition ?

Comment: That's going to be more complicated. You'll want to search on ListViews with multiple item types. If it's just a drawable that changes, you can of course just switch that drawable out in an if-else statement. If it's more complex than that, though, then yeah, look into returning multiple types of items in a ListView.

Comment: its drawable and position... do u think i should do it with if\else?

Comment: If it's just drawable and position, yeah, I'd keep it to one layout, and just switch the drawables and position based on the ChatMessage conditions.